# Only continue loop after method has finished

Tags: loops, promise, lodash

I want the following code to run synchronous.
Each `inquirer.prompt()` needs to run after the other.

This is my code now:

```
_.forEach(diff.wrongVersion, (dependency) => {
    choices = [ 'project version: ' + dependency.projectVersion, 'layer version: ' + dependency.layerVersion];
    inquirer.prompt({
        type: 'list',
        name: 'dependencies',
        message: 'Choose which version to use for ' + dependency.name,
        choices
    });
});
```

Could anybody help me with this?

I thought this could be done with `Promise` but I have no idea how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) or [`lodash#reduce`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#reduce) to achieve this type of sequential prompt.

```
diff.wrongVersion.reduce((promise, dependency) => promise.then(result =>

    inquirer.prompt({
        type: 'list',
        name: dependency.name,
        message: `Choose which version to use for: ${dependency.name}`,
        choices: [
            `project version: ${dependency.projectVersion}`,
            `layer version: ${dependency.layerVersion}`
        ]
    })

    .then(answer => Object.assign(result, answer))

), Promise.resolve({})).then(result => {
    console.log(result);
});
```

```js
// =========== Mocking Inquirer Module =====================
var inquirer = {
  prompt: function(question) {
    var choices = question.choices
      .map((v, i) => `[${i+1}] - ${v}`)
      .join('\n');
    var message = `${question.message}\n${choices}`;
    var result = {};
    var answer;
    
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    
      do {
        answer = parseInt(window.prompt(message));
      } while(
        isNaN(answer) || 
        answer < 1 || 
        answer > choices.length || 
        answer === null
      );
      
      if(answer === null) {
        reject();
      } else {
        result[question.name] = question.choices[answer-1];
        resolve(result);
      }
      
    });
    
  }
};

const diff = {
 wrongVersion: [
  {
   projectVersion: 'pv-1.0',
   layerVersion: 'lv-1.0',
   name: 'Dep-A'
  },
  {
   projectVersion: 'pv-1.0',
   layerVersion: 'lv-1.0',
   name: 'Dep-B'
  },
  {
   projectVersion: 'pv-1.0',
   layerVersion: 'lv-1.0',
   name: 'Dep-C'
  },
  {
   projectVersion: 'pv-1.0',
   layerVersion: 'lv-1.0',
   name: 'Dep-D'
  },
  {
   projectVersion: 'pv-1.0',
   layerVersion: 'lv-1.0',
   name: 'Dep-E'
  },
 ]
};


diff.wrongVersion.reduce((promise, dependency) => promise.then(result =>

 inquirer.prompt({
  type: 'list',
  name: dependency.name,
  message: `Choose which version to use for: ${dependency.name}`,
  choices: [
   `project version: ${dependency.projectVersion}`,
   `layer version: ${dependency.layerVersion}`
  ]
 })

 .then(answer => Object.assign(result, answer))

), Promise.resolve({})).then(result => {
 console.log(result);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you need the following principle:

```
var inquirer = {};

inquirer.prompt = function(object) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(function() { // <-- here I emulate async execution
      console.log('object ==> ', object);
      resolve();
    }, 1000);
  });
}

var diff = {
  wrongVersion: [{
    projectVersion: 0,
    layerVersion: 0,
    name: 'zero'
  }, {
    projectVersion: 1,
    layerVersion: 1,
    name: 'one'
  }, {
    projectVersion: 2,
    layerVersion: 2,
    name: 'two'
  }, {
    projectVersion: 3,
    layerVersion: 3,
    name: 'three'
  }]
}

var iterator = 0;

function callPrompt() {
  var dependency = diff.wrongVersion[iterator];

  var choices = ['project version: ' + dependency.projectVersion, 'layer version: ' + dependency.layerVersion];

  inquirer.prompt({
    type: 'list',
    name: 'dependencies',
    message: 'Choose which version to use for ' + dependency.name,
    choices: choices
  }).then(function() {
    iterator++;

    if (diff.wrongVersion[iterator]) {
        callPrompt();
    }
  });
};

callPrompt();
```

Example on jsfiddle (pay attention on concole) -  https://jsfiddle.net/regwtew1/2/